# How may an managed C# executable step into an Unmanaged C++ shared object's code using the Monodevelop debugger on a Ubuntu Linux 15.10 platform?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, mono, ide, c#

We would like to know how a managed C# executable running in the mono environment can step into an unmanaged C++ shared object's code using the Monodevelop debugger on a Ubuntu Linux 15.10 platform. The Monodevelop version is 5.5 and the mono version is Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4) and the .NET version is 4.5.
 I have used gdb to step into an unmanaged C++ shared object's code. However, we would like to solely use the Monodevelop debugger on a Ubuntu Linux 15.10 platform for both managed C# code and unmanaged C# code.
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was just notified that basically this is not supported  there was some attempt to make this work, but it's lacking time and interest to make it work..

https://github.com/mono/debugger-libs/tree/lldb-debugging

PullRequests are always welcome

Comment: DavidKarlas
 02:33 
not sure in theory it somewhat works but it was never made user friendly and stuff...
it would take more then 1 day just to get sense of state it’s in..
and start hacking
you could probably have something useful in ~1 week...
if you go down the path of trying to get it up and running ping me here I will give you all support I can + @Therzok authour of that prototype

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your C#/.NET solution into Monodevelop , build and run with debugging
2. ps -ef
   Please note that mono itself doesn’t fork processes except if your code does...
   your managed C# xyz.exe is loaded inside mono process and executed as one
   with no forking
3. Identify the process id(PID) of  the mono process of interest" /usr/bin/mono --debug --debugger-agent which is 7575 in this actual example
4. The Unmanaged C++ shared object should be compiled with -g for creating an symbol table.

   ~/InteroperabilityTest/MySQLVersion/Debug$ sudo gdb 7575
   GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.10-1ubuntu2) 7.10
   Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show copying"
   and "show warranty" for details.
   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
   Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.
   Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
   For help, type "help".
   Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
   7575: No such file or directory.
   (gdb) file BuildIPCameraListLinux.exe
   Reading symbols from BuildIPCameraListLinux.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
   (gdb) break ClickItCameraList.cpp:176
   No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command.
   Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
   Breakpoint 1 (ClickItCameraList.cpp:176) pending.
   (gdb) run
   Starting program: /home/venkat/InteroperabilityTest/MySQLVersion/Debug/BuildIPCameraListLinux.exe
   warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
   warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
   add-symbol-file-from-memory not supported for this target
   process 7592 is executing new program: /usr/bin/mono-sgen
   [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
   Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
   [New Thread 0x7ffff471f700 (LWP 7597)]
   Breakpoint 1, CreateSupportedCameraList () at ./ClickItCameraList.cpp:176
   176 {
   (gdb) step
   180 std::map > vendorMap;
   (gdb) step
   std::map, std::allocator >, std::less, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >::map (
   this=0x7fffffffd160) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:166
   166 : _M_t() { }
   (gdb) step
   std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >::_Rb_tree (this=0x7fffffffd160) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:807
   807 _Rb_tree() { }
   (gdb) step
   std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >::_Rb_tree_impl, false>::_Rb_tree_impl (this=0x7fffffffd160)
   at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:588
   588 _M_node_count(0)
   (gdb) continue
   Continuing.
   I AM HERE
   Save OKAY
   Program received signal SIGPWR, Power fail/restart.
   [Switching to Thread 0x7ffff471f700 (LWP 7597)]
   0x00007ffff74b60c9 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=, abstime=0x0, expected=0,
   futex=0x98a680 ) at sem_waitcommon.c:42
   42 sem_waitcommon.c: No such file or directory.
   (gdb)

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, Please look at  this answer and point out what it may be lacking? Thank you.